# Quitar último delimitador de un array

Tags: java

Necesito ayuda con un código. Tengo el siguiente formato de un array

```
Mara,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,  
Mare,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,  
Mari,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,  
Maro,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,  
Maru,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,
```

Toda esta información la tengo en un ARRAY llamado info
El código que tengo para imprimirlo es el siguiente:

```
for (int x=0; x < info.length; x++){  
    for (int y=0; y < info[x].length; y++)  
        System.out.print(info[x][y]+",");                                                               
    System.out.println("\n");  
}
```

Sin embargo, como es de esperarse, me imprime una coma al final. ¿Cómo puedo hacerle para quitar el último carácter en cada línea?, es decir, la última coma "," y cuando me imprima quede de la siguiente forma:

```
Mara,10,10,10,10,10,10,10   
Mare,10,10,10,10,10,10,10    
Mari,10,10,10,10,10,10,10    
Maro,10,10,10,10,10,10,10    
Maru,10,10,10,10,10,10,10
```

Agradeceria mucho su ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías añadir una validación con el operador ternario de Java en el método `print` de la siguiente forma:

```
for (int x = 0; x < info.length; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < info[x].length; y++) {
        System.out.print(info[x][y] + ( y == info[x].length - 1 ? "" : ","));
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}
```

Que valida que cuando se llegue al final del arreglo no imprima algún carácter.

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_ternario

Answer (score 0):

Actualmente imprimes la coma después de cada elemento del array. **NO imprimas la coma si has llegado a la última posición del array**.

```
for (int x=0; x < info.length; x++) {

    int numElements = info[x].length;
    for (int y=0; y < numElements; y++) {
        System.out.print(info[x][y]);
        if (y < (numElements - 2) {
            System.out.print(",");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();  
}
```